# PowerShell to add permission (Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks) to local user

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Please help me to write the script to add the below permisions

- Impersonate a client after authentication
- Lock Pages in Memory
- Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks

to local group using PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add [privileges](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976700.aspx), not permissions. You need the [`ntrights`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276) utility from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) for this:

```
ntrights -u DOMAIN\GROUP +r SeImpersonatePrivilege
ntrights -u DOMAIN\GROUP +r SeLockMemoryPrivilege
ntrights -u DOMAIN\GROUP +r SeManageVolumePrivilege
```

Comment: Will this support for 2008R2 machines aswell?

Answer (score 0):

If an open-source command line tool is OK, I also wrote this:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PrivMan

```
PrivMan -a DOMAIN\Group -g "SeImpersonatePrivilege SeLockMemoryPrivilege SeManageVolumePrivilege"
```

Note that the `-g` (grant), `-r` (revoke), and `-t` (test) parameters all support multiple privileges/rights.